# How to fix caller id format in iOS 8.1.2 iPhone 6+

Tags: iphone, ios8, jailbreak, mobile-country-code

I recently passed from iPhone 4 to iPhone 6+ and found unpleasant issue of caller id that I have fixed long time ago on my previous jailbroken iPhone 4 and wondering if something similar exists for iOS 8.x?

In iPhone 4 iOS 5.1 I have modified file in /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/PhoneFormats/UIMobileCountryCodes.plist with I-Funbox by changing the country code.

I tried the same with my iPhone 6+ in iOS 8.1.2 but that path and .plist file doesn't exist. Could anyone managed to fix this? Is there similar file or way to do this?

I also tried to fix this with Fix Caller ID Format iOS 8.x of Bovor.net repo through Cydia but didn't work :/
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to the problem so, someone might be interested :) In Cydia you search for application "CallerID-Format Fix iOS 5.x" and install it simply. The iPhone will restart and voilà. I tested it in iPhone 6+ with iOS 8.1.2 and it worked.